# Requery of subform shows no effect

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

If there is anybody out there who could help with my Requery coding please, I have some coding which needs to be used for Requering a form automatically, rather than me having to push the refresh button to show the results, the coding has been posted below and I have also tried some different ways but it is not automatically refreshing. If somebody has any answers, please let me know.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate
    Form![Drinks].Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Form![Drinks].Requery will never work for a subform, or even a form. It is not even one of the options I listed.

Answer (score 0):

Well the subform would have to be updated in order to fire the _AfterUpdate event, so let's assume it is firing, try Me.Requery